# how to cross just 1 trend line from a low candle to other low candle extended

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to draw just one trend line from high to high candle extended.
if I don't use barstate.islast, the script draw many lines and if I use barstate.islast the script draw a line in real time when appear new bar, but I don't want to do that, just trend one line.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Extended Trend Line", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    line.new(x1=bar_index[35], y1=low[35],x2=bar_index[5],      
            y2=low[5], color=color.blue, width=1,  
            style=line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the old line using `line.delete()`.

You can do it as below:

```
l = line.new(x1=bar_index[35], y1=low[35],x2=bar_index[5], y2=low[5], color=color.blue, width=1, style=line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
line.delete(l[1])
```

Comment: this solution delete the original line and draw the new one. I need to mantain the line between index35 and index5 in the time it has created. Only the first one.